# python+twisted+gtk: KeyboardInterrupt causes free variable?

Tags: python, variables, gtk, scope, twisted

I'm using twisted with GTK, and the following code runs when a connection could not be established:

```
def connectionFailed(self, reason):
    #show a "connect failed" dialog
    dlg = gtk.MessageDialog(
        type=gtk.MESSAGE_ERROR,
        buttons=gtk.BUTTONS_CLOSE,
        message_format="Could not connect to server:\n%s" % (
            reason.getErrorMessage()))
    responseDF = defer.Deferred()
    dlg.set_title("Connection Error")
    def response(dialog, rid):
        dlg.hide_all()
        responseDF.callback(rid)
    dlg.connect("response", response)
    dlg.show_all()

    self.shutdownDeferreds.append(responseDF)
```

`self.shutdownDeferreds` is a list of deferreds that is set up so that the reactor does not stop until they are all called.

Now, I happened to press `CTRL+C` at the same time as the connection failed. The dialog did pop up, but when I press `Close`, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DrClaud\bumhunter\gui\controller.py", line 82, in response
    dlg.hide_all()
NameError: free variable 'dlg' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DrClaud\bumhunter\gui\controller.py", line 82, in response
    dlg.hide_all()
NameError: free variable 'dlg' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope
```

Any ideas why that might happen?

Comment: Can you produce a complete, minimal example?  I noticed that this error handler is very similar to the Twisted doc/core/examples/pbgtk2.py example (which also creates a MessageDialog, closes over the variable to call a method on it, and calls show_all on it).  I wasn't able to trigger the same exception from it, though.  I tried pointing it at an unused IP and then hitting C-c while the connection was timing out; the process just exited without exception.  I also tried waiting for the dialog to pop up and then hitting C-c; same behavior.

Comment: i'll try. apparently it's not a race condition in my code, it just happens if I press C-c after the dialog pops up. actually it sometimes even happens without C-C at all... maybe i found a bug in python 2.5.4? =P

Comment: Could be.  Python has plenty of bugs, like any software. :)  I did my testing with Python 2.6.4 and PyGTK 2.16 (the versions in Ubuntu 9.10).

Comment: hey why cfan't i add bounty to this?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't that be:

```
def response(dialog, rid):
    dialog.hide_all()
    responseDF.callback(rid)
```

or really, for clarity,

```
def response(self, rid):
    self.hide_all()
    responseDF.callback(rid)
```

(I might be wrong about this, I've done barely any GTK.) If so, the problem is that you are referencing `dlg` in the function, which makes it a closure (it captures `dlg` from its surrounding scope). The `KeyboardInterrupt` will cause weird and wonderful behaviour, because it could destroy that scope.

Comment: ah the latter sentence is what I'm curious about. how can `KeyboardInterrupt` destroy the scope, which is exactly what happened here? good tip about how to make that func not a closure though

Comment: Well, Python garbage-collects variables when they pass out of scope. If you raise an error, it will propagate up the stack, passing through various scopes; as each is left, its variables will be destroyed. I've never seen this particular behaviour before; maybe someone with more GTK experience than I will weigh in on it.

Comment: "Well, Python garbage-collects variables when they pass out of scope."  No - it garbage collects *objects* (not variables) when they are no longer reachable from the root.  The dialog here is still reachable, precisely because `dlg` is closed over.  Something much weirder is happening in this example. :)

Comment: @Jean-Paul: Oops :$ -- thanks! I guess it's something to do with the GTK event loop being weird then...?